# container builds and whitelisting of dpkg

Tags: travis-ci

It would be nice if there was a "sudo" option which meant: I've made my repo container happy, but I need packages not yet whitelisted. (which is why I'm using sudo)

Then travis-ci would know which packages to prioritize getting whitelisted: this would accelerate the process of getting more source trees out of the legacy (and presumably more costly) VMs and into containers.

It would best if addon/package list, if it couldn't be satisfied from container safe packages, automatically became a legacy build, and then used sudo apt-get install to install the rest.

That would require analysis of the addon list prior to committing to legacy/container build, but would also mean that as packages are whitelisted, 
packages would move from the legacy to container build automatically.

Comment: I do not understand your question. This looks more like a feature request. Could you ask something and describe your problem?

Comment: Well, I posted pointed to this stackoverflow as a place to talk about/comment on the new container system.